# [Java WebDriver], Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to find element on closed window

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am using Selenium-server-Standalone 3.01 with IE WebDriver*32.  OS version is Window Server 2012 R2 and IE11.

I have already add the FEATURE_BFCACHE key and DWORD*32 with name iexplorer.exe in regedit.

IE11 zoom is 100% and I have enabled Protected Mode for Internet, Local Internet and Trusted Site.

But when I click the button, it give the error message like below, I can input the test in other textbox.

On my windows 10, same configuration with same code, I can run my test without error.

Comment: First, you need to show your code.  Please read [How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Second, Windows Server isn't a great place to run client side browser tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by upgrading the IE 11 to the latest version.